# Change class of an element using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

In JavaScript one can change class of an element like this

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyClass";
```

What is the alternative for doing something similar in AngularJS function? I am getting an element by using

```
var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#MyElement' ) );
```

now is there any way to change class of `var myElement`? or is it possible to do something similar to `myElement.style` ?

Comment: read about ng-class on official angular docs site

Comment: @AjaySingh I did, I even changed the css of that element using `ng-class` but that method is too lengthy. if there is an alternative for the method i asked above, it will be most efficient

Comment: Share your html and js controller code and Also look at ng-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular provides a jqLite implementation of jQuery. There are also funcitons available like

- addClass,
- removeClass
- toggleClass.

Full spec: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element